# Calendar JQuery plugin: customize view

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, calendar

Since few days, I search desperately a Calendar JQuery plugin where I could customize ordinate: In fact I would put users name in ordinate like this: http://hpics.li/3e2253e

Did you know a JQuery plugin to do this?

Thank you by advance for your help!

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very good jQuery plugin that implements the functionality you require is FullCalendar:

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

It's quite customizable, has a clear API and it's easy to use

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Finally, I've used a fork of FullCalendar with success: http://tux.fi/~jarnok/fullcalendar-resourceviews/